# Speed up procedure to resize a grid column

Tags: performance, delphi, grid, drawing, delphi-7

I have a procedure to auto-resize a column in a grid to accommodate for the largest string in that column. However when there's over 2,000 records in the grid, it takes a little too much time. Any tips on speeding this up?

```
//lstSKU = grid
procedure TfrmExcel.ResizeCol(const ACol: Integer);
var
  M: Integer;
  X: Integer;
  S: String;
  R: TRect;
begin
  M:= 20;
  lstSKU.Canvas.Font.Assign(lstSKU.Font);
  for X:= 1 to lstSKU.RowCount - 1 do begin
    S:= lstSKU.Cells[ACol, X];
    R:= Rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    DrawText(lstSKU.Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), Length(S), R,
      DT_LEFT or DT_VCENTER or DT_CALCRECT);
    if R.Right > M then
      M:= R.Right;
  end;
  M:= M + 15;
  lstSKU.ColWidths[ACol]:= M;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a standard TStringGrid/TDrawGrid?

You can iterate through using `Canvas.TextWidth(S)` instead to measure the content width of each cell, save the largest, add any padding, and then set the `Grid.ColWidths[Col] := M;`. This will trigger a single redraw if needed. (Basically what you're doing, without repeating the drawing operation 2001 times.)

```
procedure TfrmExcel.ResizeCol(const ACol: Integer);
var
  M, T: Integer;
  X: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  M := 20;

  for X := 1 to lstSKU.RowCount - 1 do 
  begin
    S:= lstSKU.Cells[ACol, X];
    T := lstSKU.Canvas.TextWidth(S);
    if T > M then
      M := T;
  end;

  M := M + 15;
  lstSKU.ColWidths[ACol] := M;
end;
```

If you want to set both width and height of the cell to accomodate larger fonts or something, use `TextExtent` instead of `TextWidth`; `TextExtent` returns a `TSize`, from which you can read `Width` and `Height`.

Comment: It's not drawing the cell on measure - the "DT_CALCRECT" on the DrawText procedure means it does not draw on the canvas - it only calculates the width of the rect. But you're right, the TextWidth should do better, although I'm pretty sure it already uses the same method to get the same result. Worth a try, I'll let you know if it helped.

Comment: Doh! Missed that `DT_CALCRECT`. I think the `TextWidth` will still be faster, though, since you don't need all of the other flags either.

Comment: Yup, that cut the time in half - except I had to modify it - TFont (at least in Delphi7) does not have a TextWidth function, but the canvas does.

Comment: modify it to use lstSKU.Canvas.TextWidth and I'll accept the answer :D

Comment: Reason I was using DrawText in the first place is because I was playing around with text wrapping, in which TCanvas.TextWidth does not know or care about wrapping. But in this case, I don't need to wrap any text, so I don't need the DrawText. Thanks.

Comment: One addition though, just before the loop starts, I put {lstSKU.Canvas.Font.Assign(lstSKU.Font);} because since I'm doing custom drawing, I often change the font of the canvas, this ensures it gets switched back appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered, I'm posting the final code, which you can use with any string grid (TStringGrid). It resized 3,000 records with 27 columns in 2.3 seconds, as opposed to the prior 6.4 average.

```
//AGrid = Grid containing column to be resized
//ACol = Column index of grid to be resized
//AMin = Minimum column width
procedure ResizeCol(AGrid: TStringGrid; const ACol, AMin: Integer);
var
  M, T: Integer; //M=Maximum Width; T=Current Text
  X: Integer; //X=Loop Counter
begin
  M:= AMin; //Begin with minimum width
  AGrid.Canvas.Font.Assign(AGrid.Font);
  for X:= 1 to AGrid.RowCount - 1 do begin
    T:= AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(AGrid.Cells[ACol, X]);
    if T > M then M:= T;
  end;
  AGrid.ColWidths[ACol]:= M + AMin;
end;
```